# Who is Dumbledore referring to when he says "Lily and James put their faith in the wrong person"?

Tags: harry-potter

In the last movie of the Harry Potter series, Dumbledore tells Snape the following after Snape finds out that Lily dies.

> Lily and James put their faith in the wrong person and so did you.

Is Dumbledore referring to himself or someone else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's obviously Peter Pettigrew.

He betrayed their location to Lord Voldemort as he was the secret keeper to the Fidelius charm.

Snape put his faith in Lord Voldemort as he was a Death Eater before turning to Dumbledore.

Comment: Didn't think Dumbledor knew about PP at that point, common knowledge was that Sirius Black was the traitor to the Potters so doesn't Dumbledor mean SB?

Answer (score 8):

Dumbledore is presumably not referring to himself. If he was referring to himself then that would mean that he is saying that they put their faith in him to protect them and he failed them, which would then presumably mean that it is also Dumbledore whom Snape put his faith in to protect Lily and James and Dumbledore failed him as well. However, in the book, in the very next sentence Dumbledore clarifies that the wrong person whom Snape put his faith in was actually Voldemort:

> "She and James put their faith in the wrong person," said Dumbledore. "Rather like you, Severus. Weren't you hoping that Lord Voldemort would spare her?"

Presumably, then, Dumbledore was referring to the friend of Lily and James who betrayed them. In reality that person was Peter Pettigrew, who had replaced Sirius Black as Secret-Keeper at the last minute, but at that point in the story Dumbledore was not aware of the switch, and thus in his mind the traitor would have been Sirius Black. As Dumbledore said to Harry and Hermione in Chapter Twenty-One of *Prisoner of Azkaban*:

> "There is not a shred of proof to support Black's story, except your word – and the word of two thirteen-year-old wizards will not convince anybody. A street full of eyewitnesses swore they saw Sirius murder Pettigrew. I myself gave evidence that Sirius had been the Potters' Secret-Keeper."

Answer (score 6):

Dumbledore clearly means the secret keeper for the Fidelius charm that protected their whereabouts.

> He likely believes at this point that Sirius Black was the keeper, when it in fact was Peter Pettigrew.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer